# Why can't I access a network device using its hostname?

Tags: networking, dns, hostname

I've got an embedded Linux device whose hostname is **xplained-d4**. Both it (10.0.0.139), a Windows laptop (10.0.0.115) and an Ubuntu laptop (10.0.0.117) are connected to the same network switch via wired ethernet. I have no problem pinging and SSH'ing into the device from the Windows machine using the hostname **xplained-d4**, however, I can't do that from the Ubuntu laptop. When I try to ping the device it just says **ping: unknown host xplained-d4**.

Comment: Are your ubuntu laptop using the same DNS as your windows machine ?

Comment: @SorenA On the Windows machine, running **ipconfig /all** shows that it is 10.0.0.1. On the Linux machine, the contents of /etc/resolv.conf show the nameserver as being 127.0.1.1, but running **nmcli dev show | grep DNS** shows 10.0.0.1. So I'm not sure on the Linux machine.

Comment: Did you try "xplained-64.local" ?

Comment: @Jean-Marie I did, unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: what are the DHCP and DNS servers setting for the Windows and Ubuntu machines? Compare them by 1) ipconfig /all in Windows from a terminal , 2) ifconfig -a from an Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: @AndreaBorga Winows: DHCP and DNS 10.0.0.1. On linux, **ifconfig -a** doesn't show that information. The contents of /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases shows that the DNS and DHCP servers are 10.0.0.1

Comment: @AmrBekhit can you  ssh using the IP address with ubuntu?

Comment: @AndreaBorga yes, using the IP address I can SSH to the device.

Comment: did you try to force the DNS settings in the network manager GUI?